# How do I know if a AWS Server instance has license SQL Server Standard or SQL Server Web?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, aws, license

I'm looking my AWS billing and this doubt has come up. How do I know if a specific instance is running SQL Server 2008-R2 Standard or SQL Server Web? (using the AWS Console or SQL Server Management Studio)

The Management Studio About shows the following:

Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio `10.50.2806.0`
Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools `10.50.2806.0`
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC) `6.1.7601.17514`
Microsoft MSXML `3.0 6.0`
Microsoft Internet Explorer `9.0.8112.16421`
Microsoft .NET Framework `2.0.50727.5456`
Operating System `6.1.7601`

Looking for version `10.50.2806.0`, I've saw that it may be related for both licenses ([link](http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/2567616)), so I don't know how to distinguish them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run `SELECT @@VERSION;` in a query window, with results to text. You will see something like this (minor details will vary) in the Messages pane:

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.2402.0 (X64) 
    Aug 13 2014 11:36:34 
    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
    Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.4 <X64> (Build 9841: )
----^^^^^^^^^ edition will be here
```

Help > About in Management Studio is just about the client tools, so may not even reflect the same version as the server, never mind that Management Studio no longer has any edition differentiations.

Answer (score 1):

You can run `SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('edition')` in a query window.

Your output will be something like: `Standard Edition (64-bit)` or `Web Edition (64-bit)`.

More info: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174396.aspx).